# $|b|^{\frac {1}{\log b}}= |a|^{\frac {1}{\log a}}$ implies $|b|=b^ {\lambda}$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

I was studying 'Ostrowski's Theorem' stating that "Every non-trivial valuation on $\Bbb Q$ is equivalent either to a $p-$adic valuation or to the ordinary absolute value.

While reading the proof I have reached a point where the book says that for all integers $a,b >1$ if we have $$|b|^{\frac {1}{\log b}}= |a|^{\frac {1}{\log a}}$$

where $||$ is a valuation on $\Bbb Q$.

Then it follows that $$|b|=b^ {\lambda}$$ for all integer $b>1$ and for some $\lambda$ independent of $b$.

I can't solve this line of reason. Please help.

**Book is "Local Fields" by J.W.S Cassels**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $c:=|b|^{\frac {1}{log b}}= |a|^{\frac {1}{log a}}.$ Then we have
$$
|b|=c^{\log(b)}=e^{\log(c)\log(b)}=b^{\log(c)}=b^{\lambda}.
$$
Hence $|b|=|b|_{\infty}^{\lambda}$, where $|b|_{\infty}$ is the usual absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$.